# Multi-client java architecture

Tags: java, spring, architecture

I'm building a Web-application in java, with Spring (and spring security), struts2 and hibernate.

Every "User" belongs to a "Client". And i need to design it so that when a User is logged in, he will only have access to the resources of his "Client"

Originally the web-app was built without "Clients". Just Users with Roles that had ROLE-based access to certain modules of the web-app.

These Roles shall continue on. Only difference is that Users are to be limited to the Client resources only. Within the Client they have ROLE-based access that describe what they can and can not do.

Architecture-wise I have a pretty standard web-app, with Managers and Dao's.
So what is the best architecture approach to this?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: in case you want to google it, the word you are looking for is `multi-tenancy`.

Comment: thanks for that. i was looking for that keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something similar working. You can add "clientId" extra attribute, for example, to the default UserDetails (is you have not yet a customized one) so once user is logged, the applications knows the client you user belongs to.

When the user wants to perform an action, the application should get the "clientId" from the userDetails and perform the action according with this id. Problay, many of your DAO methods (and tables) should have the clientId as a parameter.

This solution doesn't affect the Roles.

Comment: Yep, this is what im probably need to do. I was kind of hoping there was some sort of standardized framework or "plugin" to use so i would have to rewrite a lot of code.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way. If you want your application to be multi-tenancy, you  need to change your database model, you application and so on.